# Java Swing want to keep Radio button selection after Restart

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, selection

Friends

I am a beginner and trying to develop a system level java swing software.

I have 2 JRadio buttons viz A & B in a RadioButton group bg.

I want to keep the radio button selection after restart or until further selection.

Searched for this long in net but getting code for PHP,HTML etc.
Somebody please help me.

```
rdbtA = new JRadioButton("A");
        contentPane.add(rdbtA);
        
        rdbtB = new JRadioButton("B");
        contentPane.add(rdbtB);
        
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(A);
        bg.add(B);
```

Comment: I use a `.txt` file to save properties before exiting my program. You can try creating a file and saving your properties in it, for example write `1` if first radio button is selected and `2` if second one is selected. Just read this file when your program starts and set properties accordingly. If you don't know how to read/write a file, follow this tutorial : https://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/how-to-read-and-write-text-file-in-java

Comment: Thanks@Peter for your reply. Which would be better whether using .txt file or making an additional table in the mysql already associated with the software?

Comment: The thing is, I don't know anything about MySql. That's why, I use `.txt` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start your application all the graphic components ar re-created, so you have to **save the selection** in some way when you close your program or when the selection changes (the easiest is to save your choice in a file) and **restore it** when the software is started (after the buttons creation).

Let me explain this in code:

```
rdbtA = new JRadioButton("A");
contentPane.add(rdbtA);

rdbtB = new JRadioButton("B");
contentPane.add(rdbtB);

/*
 1. If exists a save-file, open it (else, ignore 2. and 3.)
 2. read the value of previous A and previous B
 3. Set these values to rdbtA and rdbtB
*/

//Rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks @Calaf I will make a table in mysql for it.